# PayPal payments to multiple receivers. Adaptive Payments?

Tags: php, paypal

I am looking to develop an application that is effectively a cart based software licensing management system.

In most scenarios, the cart system will be entirely owned by one vendor, therefore no matter what items are added to the cart, only one person will need to receive the money.

In feedback from potential users, there are some who desire the cart system to be shared and contain a mix of products that could be sold by multiple people, therefore the total payment for the cart could need to be received between multiple people.

e.g.

```
Product A
Sold by Developer A
$10

Product B
Sold by Developer B
$15

Product C
Sold by Developer C
$20

Product D
Sold by Developer A
$15
```

If a buyer adds all of the above to their cart, they should pay $60. But Developer A should receive $25, Developer B $15, and Developer C $20.

So, of course, for the sake of being user friendly, I want that process to be entirely transparent to the end user, e.g. they are just making one transaction worth $60, but behind the scenes PayPal and the application should split that between the correct recipients.

So, is that possible with the PayPal API. And is that possible with Adaptive Payments? Is there a good code example (PHP) that covers this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is possible with Adaptive Payments, specifically the [Pay API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/).

My [PHP class library for PayPal](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library) will make this very quick and easy for you, and it includes a [fully functional chained payment sample](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library/blob/master/samples/Pay-Chained.php).

Comment: Long time no speak! Thank you for this answer, it is just what I need. I think I will be implementing your library -- work on this part is somewhat delayed at this point!